# Access ContainerView from embeded view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, containers

I have a few container views layed out that each get a view controller embeded in. I'm trying to get the y position of each container view but dont know how to quite go about it. I've tried accessing it through the segue with `[segue destinationViewController]` but that only gives me the embeded VC's y coordinate, which is 0 inside of the container view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try going through your view's subviews:

```
[yourView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"View %lu: %f",(unsigned long)idx,obj.frame.origin.y);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make IBOutlets to the container views in your container controller, then access those properties from the embedded controllers with `self.parentViewController.propertyName`.